# How to read environment files from e2e tests?

Tags: angular, cypress, angular-e2e

Here's the structure of my Angular application:

```
MyApplication
  apps
      - app1
          - src
              - app
              - assets
              - environments //*****USE THIS FILES ****

      - app1-e2e
          - src
              - fixtures
              - integration
              - plugins
              - supports
```

I'm using Cypress for the e2e tests. For instance, I want to use the base URL, so that it depends on the environment (local, dev, ...):

```
it('should redirect to release', () => {
  cy.get('[data-testid="my-link"]').click();
  cy.url().should('include', 'http://localhost.homedepot.com:4200/');
});
```

if it's the development machine, it will be `localhost.homedepot.com:4200`. However, if the dev machine it will be `myapplication-np.mycompany.com`, and so forth.

We already have all this information in the environment files. Should I duplicate them in the `e2e` folder or is there a way to read them from the environment files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a way to quickly switch my environment when I need to, hope it helps.

To use it, add these lines to your `cypress/plugins/index.js`

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

  // quick env switch
  if (config.env.target) {
      const { baseUrl, ...currentEnv } = config.env[config.env.target];
      config.baseUrl = baseUrl;
      config.env = { ...config.env, ...currentEnv }
  }

  return config;

}
```

Now you need to set your target environment and configure your environments like this:

In your `cypress.json`:

```json
  ...
  "env": {
    "target": "dev",
    "dev": {
      "baseUrl": "http://www.myappurl-dev.com",
      "apiUrl": "http://www.myapiurl-dev.com",
      "username": "admin_dev"
    },
    "test": {
      "baseUrl": "http://www.myappurl-test.com",
      "apiUrl": "http://www.myapiurl-test.com",
      "username": "admin_test"
    }
  },
  ...
```

You can also set an environment in your `cypress.env.json` which should be in your `.gitignore` so it won't be pushed to your remote repo.

`cypress.env.json`:

```json
{
  "target": "local",
  "local": {
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4000",
    "apiUrl": "http://localhost:22742",
    "username": "admin_local"
}
```

Finally, all you need to do is change `target` in `cypress.json` or `cypress.env.json` to quickly switch between your environments.
Remember that any value set in `cypress.env.json` overwrite the ones set in `cypress.json`.

And then in your code, you would use it like this:

```js
it('should redirect to release', () => {
  cy.get('[data-testid="my-link"]').click();
  cy.url().should('include', Cypress.config('baseUrl');
});
```

---

Edit #1
If your environment config already exists somewhere:
Have a look at how to set environment values from `cypress/plugins/index.js` [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-5-Plugins). They are showing how to get your `.env`, but you might also be able to read a `.config` file.

---

Edit #2:
I was able to read my `root/src/web.config` from `cypress/plugins/index.js` using `fs` and `xml-js`:

```js
const convert = require('xml-js');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    const xmlAngularConfig = fs.readFileSync('../path/to/your/config/file', 'utf8');
    const jsonAngularConfig = convert.xml2json(xmlAngularConfig, { compact: true, spaces: 4 });

    // Then you can add any value of jsonAngularConfig to cypress config
    config.baseUrl = jsonAngularConfig.url;

   // Don't forget to return config
   return config;
}
```

Comment: @PeaceAndQuit, you are still duplicating the information by creating new files with configuration information. Is there a way to use the information already existing in the environment files. Please take a look at the structure of the angular application that I included in the beginning of the question.

Comment: I want just to know. If it's not possible and/or not recommended, I can duplicate those information. I don't have a problem with that. I wanted just to know whether I can already reuse the same information existing in the environment files before duplicating them.

Comment: You're right, you should come up with a way to read your environment file from `cypress/plugins/index.js`. That's where you have access to config before everything else loads.

Comment: and that was the main purpose of my question. `Is it possible to read environment files of the main angular application from the e2e folder`.

Comment: Yes, as stated in my edit, you can set your environment from the `plugins/index.js` and since this file executes in the NodeJS environment, you can use `fs` or any other node package to get your config file wherever it is and merge it to cypress config.